# How to make a generic id class in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Coming from a Java background, I know that for example an ID can be implemented as a generic like this:

```
public class Id<T> {

    private String _id;

    private Id(String idString) {
        this._id = idString;
    }

    public static <Type> Id<Type> valueOf(String idString) {
        return new Id<Type>(idString);
    }
}

Id<ObjectA> a = Id.valueOf("1");
Id<ObjectB> b = Id.valueOf("1");
```

In this example, even though both IDs hold the String "1", they cannot be compared since their generic types are different.

I'm trying to implement the same structure in Python and started out with a NamedTuple:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Id(NamedTuple):

    id: str

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Id):
            return False
        else:
            if self.id != other.id:
                return False
        return True
```

I want to bring generics in so that I can create an Id just like in Java. Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: I think you have an extra pair of O in the first snippet, of missing one

Comment: What do you mean "just like in Java"? What specific features and behaviors do you care about? Python is a very different language.

Comment: What exactly is `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`? Just two random arbitrary objects? But anyways, yes, the PEP 484 type system includes support [for generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html). The [NewType](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#newtypes) construct is also potentially relevant here.

Comment: ObjectA and ObjectB are two random arbitrary objects, yes. What I mean by "just like in Java" is that I want to have a generic ID class. If, for example, I had users and products which have an ID, I could have one ID-class as shown above and create IDs of type `Id<User>` and `Id<Product>` and even though they internally might have the same string, comparing them would give me an error since their generic types are different.